# Serial2 of ESP32 not responding( NEO 6M GPS)

Tags: serial-port, gps, arduino-ide, esp32

I am doing an Autonomous Car project and I have a NEO 6M GPS module, I am using an ESp32 as the board, the module works fine with Arduino and Nodemcu. but not with ESP32, the reason being it not supporting software serial, so I took help from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwShqW39jlE&feature=emb_title

I added hardware serial but still, there is no output I have provided the code below

```
#include<HardwareSerial.h>//No extra libray installed
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17

HardwareSerial gps_serial(2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.printf("LETS START");
 gps_serial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
}

void loop() {
  while (gps_serial.available()) {
   Serial.print(char(gps_serial.read()));  // read from gps, write to serial debug port
  Serial.print("I am here");
  }
}
```

The output on the serial monitor is  `LETS START`
The other code which worked on other boards is also provided below, edited to work in ESP32

```
#include <WiFi.h>
//#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>

#include <TinyGPS++.h> // library for GPS module
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
TinyGPSPlus gps;  // The TinyGPS++ object
//SoftwareSerial ss(4, 5); // The serial connection to the GPS device
HardwareSerial Serial2(2);


const char* ssid = "***********"; //ssid of your wifi
const char* password = "***********"; //password of your wifi
float latitude , longitude;
int year , month , date, hour , minute , second;
String date_str , time_str , lat_str , lng_str;
int pm;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup()
{  Serial2.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //ss.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //connecting to wifi
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)// while wifi not connected
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("."); //print "...."
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  // Print the IP address
}


void loop()
{
  while (Serial2.available() > 0) //while data is available
    if (gps.encode(Serial2.read())) //read gps data
    {
      if (gps.location.isValid()) //check whether gps location is valid
      {
        latitude = gps.location.lat();
        lat_str = String(latitude , 6); // latitude location is stored in a string
        longitude = gps.location.lng();
        lng_str = String(longitude , 6); //longitude location is stored in a string
      }
      if (gps.date.isValid()) //check whether gps date is valid
      {
        date_str = "";
        date = gps.date.day();
        month = gps.date.month();
        year = gps.date.year();
        if (date < 10)
          date_str = '0';
        date_str += String(date);// values of date,month and year are stored in a string
        date_str += " / ";

        if (month < 10)
          date_str += '0';
        date_str += String(month); // values of date,month and year are stored in a string
        date_str += " / ";
        if (year < 10)
          date_str += '0';
        date_str += String(year); // values of date,month and year are stored in a string
      }
      if (gps.time.isValid())  //check whether gps time is valid
      {
        time_str = "";
        hour = gps.time.hour();
        minute = gps.time.minute();
        second = gps.time.second();
        minute = (minute + 30); // converting to IST
        if (minute > 59)
        {
          minute = minute - 60;
          hour = hour + 1;
        }
        hour = (hour + 5) ;
        if (hour > 23)
          hour = hour - 24;   // converting to IST
        if (hour >= 12)  // checking whether AM or PM
          pm = 1;
        else
          pm = 0;
        hour = hour % 12;
        if (hour < 10)
          time_str = '0';
        time_str += String(hour); //values of hour,minute and time are stored in a string
        time_str += " : ";
        if (minute < 10)
          time_str += '0';
        time_str += String(minute); //values of hour,minute and time are stored in a string
        time_str += " : ";
        if (second < 10)
          time_str += '0';
        time_str += String(second); //values of hour,minute and time are stored in a string
        if (pm == 1)
          time_str += " PM ";
        else
          time_str += " AM ";
      }
    }

 WiFiClient client = server.available(); // Check if a client has connected
  if (!client)
  {
    return;
  }
  // Prepare the response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>GPS DATA</title> <style>";
  s += "a:link {background-color: YELLOW;text-decoration: none;}";
  s += "table, th, td </style> </head> <body> <h1  style=";
  s += "font-size:300%;";
  s += " ALIGN=CENTER> GPS DATA</h1>";
  s += "<p ALIGN=CENTER style=""font-size:150%;""";
  s += "> <b>Location Details</b></p> <table ALIGN=CENTER style=";
  s += "width:50%";
  s += "> <tr> <th>Latitude</th>";
  s += "<td ALIGN=CENTER >";
  s += lat_str;
  s += "</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Longitude</th> <td ALIGN=CENTER >";
  s += lng_str;
  s += "</td> </tr> <tr>  <th>Date</th> <td ALIGN=CENTER >";
  s += date_str;
  s += "</td></tr> <tr> <th>Time</th> <td ALIGN=CENTER >";
  s += time_str;
  s += "</td>  </tr> </table> ";

  s += "</body> </html>";

  client.print(s); // all the values are send to the webpage
  delay(100);
}
```

I do get the IP address on the serial monitor when I run it but when I access that address the fields are blank.
So what I understand is that the Serial communication with the GPS module is not working. I tried many other solutions on net but no use at all.

**I am using ESP32 DevKit V1, 30 pins version**

Comment: Your basic sketch should work, just make sure that you connect to the GPS correctly, that is ESP32 pin 16 to TX of GPS, and ESP32 pin 17 to Rx of GPS.

Comment: I did something, I put a serial.print("flag") at the beginning of each loop(each flag with a number), I found that the program enters void loop but nothing more, so I changed the pins from 16&17 to 2&4, now it enters into the while (Serial2.available() > 0), but nothing more, what can i interfere from this?

Comment: @hcheung it worked!!!! You were right, the pins were reversed, I did not thoroughly go through ur comment until now, I was referring some books when I read that the pins need to be oppositely connected. Now I do get the coordinates. I had to use 9600 as the baud rate. Thank you very much

Comment: @hcheung Can you please post your answer separately so I can upvote and mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing which ESP32 Module you use exactly, there are two show stoppers
NEO-6M GPS Module needs 5 V, ESP32 pins deliver max 3.6V - normaly 3.3V
Some ESP32 modules block certain pins to use them for SD card, camera, lcd or other on board features. So look up the datasheet of your esp32 board variant.

The code should be ok if HWSerial2 exists 
If you use ESP32 version below 1.03 you have to define HWSerial,
ESP32 1.04 up this is not necessary any more

```
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17
...
HardwareSerial Serial2(2);

...
Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
```

and 5V power is supplied to the GSM module.

Edit 2: Credit to hcheung asking the most basic thing
The solution was the OP had RX to RX and TX to TX, instead of RX ESP pin to RX on GPS and vice versa.
So problem solved

Comment: I am using ESP32 DevKit V1(30 pins version), and the GPS module works just fine when used with Nodemcu, which also gives 3.3v output right?

Comment: I have also some hardware that "works"  with NodeMcu v1.0,1.1 but not with ESP32 due to the 3.3V. The "problem" is that it may work if not in the spec or it may not. So my guess with the 3.3V was in the right direction, You could use stepup module (2Eur) if the max A is sufficient or for testing a usb powered TTL-Module (only 5V and GND) or a cut USB Cable (only 5V and GND) and a powerbank. 2 Tips - loop 1st line change to  while (Serial2.available()) {  AND get rid of the String classon ESP. It will lead to heap fragmentation and unregular crashes and resets

Comment: I will check with the 5v, I have a 5v coming from the motor driver I will use that and reply soon, I did not understand String classon ESP???

Comment: Regarding String class: You convert for example lng_str = String(longitude , 6); instead of using the already defined char array. Instead of using += to append Strings work with strcpy and strcat to aggregate the char array parts -This will prevent crashes because of memory fragmentation (heap) especially if you use glabaly defined fix char arrays for the manipulation of data.
      }

Comment: I will try that, I used 5V from an Arduino Uno instead of 3.3v from the esp32, but still no luck

Comment: Have you checked the version of IDE should be 1.8.12 and the esp32 core must be 1.04 that the program works this way Look my edit in the answer

Comment: IDE is 1.8.12, and esp32 board installed is 1.04, I checked your edit but shouldn't it be serial2.begin() instead of serial.begin()???

Comment: In your case yes it should be serial2. There is an issue with serial2 though on ESP32 when using bidirectional communication, so you should try serial1 also.If that does not work, I cant help anymore because I have no Neogps to test.

Comment: I tried with Serial2 and Serial1, but no luck either

Comment: I did something, I put a serial.print("flag") at the beginning of each loop(each flag with a number), I found that the program enters void loop but nothing more, so I changed the pins from 16&17 to 2&4, now it enters into the while (Serial2.available() > 0), but nothing more, what can i interfere from this?

Comment: Get rid of the delay at the end of the loop and try to flush the serial buffer like Serial2.flush(); at the end of the setup - perhaps some gps calibration data garbles the buffer.

Comment: It worked,@hcheung, suggested me to check the pins and it was not oppositely connected, I had them directly connected, tx to tx and rx to rx

Comment: Can you mark as solved - I added final solution and credit to hcheung